# kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" -> Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource

Tags: kubernetes

Small Kubernetes API question please.

(This is not helm related btw)

I am just running a basic `kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1"`

However, I got the following as result: `Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource`

I am a bit confused here, hope this technical question is not too much of a trouble.

What does it even mean?

Is it because I failed to create something? (I never created this "custom.metrics.k8s.io" myself)

Maybe some kind of credential issues?

How can I root cause, troubleshoot and fix this please?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your result of this command, kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io"?

Comment: kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io"

Comment: returns Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource

Comment: both returns the same thing 

Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource

Comment: Are you using helm to install Prometheus adaptor? If so, could you confirm that the custom metrics API service is running on the namespace shared with Prometheus adaptor?

Comment: Could you share why you want to query this api resource? Have you deployed any APIService that would include the `custom.metrics.k8s.io`? I'd reckon this could shed some light on the topic (from `APIService` perspective) : https://sysdig.com/blog/kubernetes-autoscaler/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the APIs with for example:

```
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  name: v1beta1.custom.metrics.k8s.io
spec:
  service:
    name: prometheus-adapter
    namespace: monitoring
  group: custom.metrics.k8s.io
  version: v1beta1
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  groupPriorityMinimum: 100
  versionPriority: 100
```

This works with kube-prometheus. Maybe you have to change `spec.service.name` and `spec.service.namepsace` for whatever you use as a monitoring service.

I found this [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter/blob/master/deploy/manifests/custom-metrics-apiservice.yaml), but had to change the version of `apiregistration.k8s.io` from `v1beta1` to `v1`.